# Why does loading an object with session.get doesn't persist object modifications at the end of session?

Tags: java, hibernate

Maybe I misunderstood the semantics of get and merge in hibernate, but if I do this (in a Spring method controller, so using service and dao layers):

```
ClassMy a = service.get(234, ClassMy.class) (this loads the object using session.get)

a.setPropertyX("test");
```

this will not result in a automatic update. Instead, if I already had "a" in memory I would do:

```
a = (ClassMy) service.merge(a);
a.setPropertyX("test");
```

this results in a update.

Do I have to merge the object after loading it with get? Sounds so strange...

Comment: Stupid me, the only wrong thing was that the propertyX was already set to "test". In that situation hibernate won't do anything. Setting it to "test2" after load and the committing, will result in a update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have something wrong.

The first snippet should work, provided it's executed in the same transaction as the `service.get` call (i.e. the transaction should be started by the method containing this snippet, and not by the `service.get` method).

In the second snippet, if it runs in a transaction, then it should work: it loads the entity from the session, then copy the state of the detached a to the attached entity, then modifies the property of the attched entity. If it doesn't run in a transaction, (i.e. if it's service.merge which starts the transaction), the merge will work, but the change of the property will be done on a detached entity, and the new value of the property won't be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure a transaction is there. Starting a transaction, call "Save" and then commit the transaction is mandatory.